# How to extract all child div's classes with imacros

Tags: imacros

After selecting parent div, is it possible to extract all child div's classes ?

I want this in pure imacros not with javascript or VB

Thanks

Comment: I suggest ‘… EXTRACT=HTM’ and parse it with regular expressions in the command ‘EVAL’. (This problem requires most likely an “ad hoc” approach.)

Comment: @Shugar Thanks sorted :D

Answer (score 0):

You can try with positon chnage

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:someclass
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=DIV ATTR:CLASS:subclass
TAG POS=R2 TYPE=DIV ATTR:CLASS:subclass
```